# Selecting a unique identifier in VBA/SQL

Tags: vba, excel

I run a macro which updates multiple entries in an SQL server Database.

```
sSqlClose = "UPDATE [header] SET tskstatus = 'closed' WHERE [tskstatus] = 'open'"
sSqlClose = "INSERT INTO dbo.detail (title, closed, closedby) VALUES ('" & updtitle & "', 'GETUTCDATE()', (Select initials from USER_PARAMS where User_ID=" & sqluserfix & ")"
```

Basically, I wish only update a certain field that holds a unique ID.

In this instance, the unique number in the data base is the date.

So the titles in my database looks like this... tskno, date, title, closed, closedby.

I wish to only update an entry with a certain date. So for example....

```
tskno, date,     title,   closed,   closedby
13     12/03/14           12/03/14  ME
14     12/04/14           12/04/14  YOU '<< This line is bold in the spreadsheet
15     12/04/14           12/04/14  HIM
```

I wish to only select and update the entry that is **BOLD** by using the date as the unique identifier.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first line of code you are updating entries based on a unique identifier.  You should be able to use

```
"UPDATE yourTable SET itemToBeChanged = newValue WHERE date = '12/04/14'"
```

to do what you are asking for.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That does help thank you! The only issue is 12/04/14 is a value from a cell in an Excel sheet which has been entered in the database. So I would need to refer to the Cell value as one entry in the database could be 12/04/14 but another value could 12/05/14, if you get me? I need to write something along the lines of...UPDATE [HEADER] SET tskstatus WHERE cell value = "close" WHERE cell value = "12/04/14"....I know thats not right but can you see what result I am trying to get?